# declare variable in a table in SQL

Tags: sql-server

I have a below query that requires help

```
Declare @DB varchar(3) 
set @DB = 'C01' 
SELECT * FROM SVBNORD+@DB WHERE ORDER_DATE = ''
```

But I get a message

```
Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 3
Incorrect syntax near '+'.
```

Can you please help me correct my statement.

Comment: You can't use variables in a table name in regular SQL, you'll have to use Dynamic SQL for that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use `execute` to dynamically call the query:

```
Declare @DB varchar(3) 
set @DB = 'C01' 

execute ('SELECT * FROM SVBNORD'+@DB+' WHERE ORDER_DATE = '''' ')
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't do this in normal sql. You can however build up sql dynamically and execute it, like so:

```
DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(MAX);

SET @sql = 
'SELECT * FROM SVBNORD' + @DB + N'WHERE ORDER_DATE = ''''';
EXEC(@sql);
```

You'll need to double up any single quotes in the query.